# @link decorator in django rest framework as a list controller

Tags: django-rest-framework

so i want to filter all the sales invoices using url .. e.g.

```
/api/v1/invoice/sales/
```

i think the best way to do this is by using @link method in the viewset. here is my code ..

```
@link()
def sales(self, request, pk):
    qs = Invoice.objects.filter(is_sales=True)
    serializer = InvoiceSerializer(qs)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

but when i go to '/api/v1/invoice/sales/', and use breakpoints, the script doesn't stop at any point..

what am i doing wrong here?

//mouse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `@link()` and `@action()` decorators are only linked to the detail-endpoints (`/api/v1/invoice/{pk}/sales/` in your case), see [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#marking-extra-methods-for-routing).

However, there is a third-party library ([drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions)) that adds these decorators on a collection level.