# Not able to call decorator inner function in Django view

Tags: python, django

I am facing an issue today, here is my Django class based view and decorator.

```
def my_decorator(view_func):
    def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print "I am here"
        # maybe do something before the view_func call
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # maybe do something after the view_func call
        return response
    return wraps(view_func)(_decorator)

class ConfigletList(APIView):
    """
    List all Configlets, or create a new Configlet.
    """
    @my_decorator
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        configlets = Configlet.objects.filter(status = True).order_by('name')
        serializer = ConfigletSerializer(configlets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ConfigletSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

From get request I am calling a decorator to access request object in `_decorator` function. But it is not getting called. Please do let me know what is the issue in this code. I never faced any such issue in decorator  before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156686/how-to-apply-decorator-do-dispatch-method-in-class-based-views-django

Comment: I think you are using DRF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488800/link-decorator-in-django-rest-framework-as-a-list-controller

Comment: in class based views, we apply decorator on `dispatch` method by converting it to method decorator